# sign 2 things at once

Tags: signature

When a user unlocks their private key can two things be signed at once?

such as a message as well as a transaction, where the transaction is basically just another message that is meant to be broadcast to the network

even when using a wallet like Metamask I would like only 1 popup to appear.

Comment: You don't "unlock your private key", you unlock your account using your private key.

Comment: @goodvibration k, I'll mull over the semantical difference and practicality... any thoughts on whether the account can then be used to sign multiple things at once without further user input?

Comment: Your question is too broad and requires some more context in order to be addressed. Please share some code and be more specific as to what it is exactly that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit two transactions or messages for signing by just submitting both asynchronously but Metamask will still require the user to approve each. They will appear in the same popup, though.